# Does git cherry-pick save any metadata?

Tags: git

Given a commit that is cherry-picked into master from a branch, and later that branch is merged back into master:

How does git know that the changes coming from the previous cherry-pick should not collide with the changes from the merge? Is any sort of metadata saved with the cherry-picked commit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, and there's nothing special about the act of cherry-picking, either.  Git will *always* notice when the exact same change has been made on either side of a merge.  The commits don't even have to look anything alike; as long as some chunk of text started the same way and ended up the same way, there's no reason to mark it as a conflict.

Comment: so it's safe to say that if I copy and paste some text or cherry-pick the same changes, for git that's equivalent?

Comment: @Z.Khullah should be, yep!

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn’t store any metadata, and in general I would be
careful/wary about mixing cherry-picks and merges.

It will go well in simple cases but can be annoying in slightly more
complex cases.

#### When it goes well.

Given this repository:[1]

```
Init - a --bc
         \ b
```

(`bc` is a cherry-pick of `b`)

The merge will go fine:

```
Init - a --bc - M
         \ b  - /
```

I guess because the two branches introduced the same changes since they
diverged at `a`.

#### When it doesn’t work

But this won’t work:[2]

```
Init - a --bc ----- M [conflict]
         \ b  - d /
```

The difference here is that we made an additional commit `d` on the side
branch.

One might think that git-merge(1) will:

1. Look backwards on both branches until it finds the same state (`bc`
   and `b`)
2. Figure out that only `side` (with `d`) introduced any changes since
   then
3. Go through with the merge

But that’s not what happens.

On the other hand, cherry-picking `d` into the branch will work:

```
Init - a --bc - dc
         \ b  - d
```

So given that we can’t reproduce the same state (automatically,
conflict-free) by interleaving these two commands, I would say that they
are not interchangeable.

And of course if you hadn’t done any cherry-picks then the merge would
have gone fine (could also fast-forward):[3]

```
Init - a ---------- M
         \ b -- d /
```

---

#### Update: a more thorough explanation

After I wrote this I found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180312-00/?p=98215), which starts with the same basic example but goes into more detail.

#### Setup (1)

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -mInit
echo a > file && git add a && git commit -ma
git checkout -b side
echo b > file && git add file && git commit -mb
git checkout -
git cherry-pick -x side
git merge side
```

#### Setup (2)

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -mInit
echo a > file && git add a && git commit -ma
git checkout -b side
echo b > file && git add file && git commit -mb
git checkout -
git cherry-pick -x side
git checkout -
echo d > file && git add file && git commit -md
git checkout -
git merge side
```

#### Setup (3)

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -mInit
echo a > file && git add a && git commit -ma
git checkout -b side
echo b > file && git add file && git commit -mb
echo d > file && git add file && git commit -md
git checkout -
git merge --no-ff side
```